# Show content if page is a grandchild of top level page

Tags: pages, query, conditional-tags

I'm looking to show a certain block of content if the current page is a grandchild of a top level page.

This is my current page heirarchy;

```
- Top Level Page
    - Child Page
        - Grandchild Page
        - Grandchild Page
        - Grandchild Page
    - Child Page
        - Grandchild Page
        - Grandchild Page
        - Grandchild Page
    - Child Page
        - Grandchild Page
        - Grandchild Page
        - Grandchild Page
```

So the top level page has 3 children, each of which have 3 children of their own. How can I target ONLY the grandchildren?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how many ancestors the page has via [`get_post_ancestors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors):

```
// grandchild pages will have two or more ancestors
if( 2 <= count( get_post_ancestors( $post->ID ) ) ){
    echo 'grandchild page';
}
```